# How to REMOVE UNITY at 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, compiz, uninstall, kde

I'm a relative new user in linux, I have a laptop with low-medium hardware, Unity goes OK but when I work with web browser or 3-5 windows and applications , crashes and gets slow. I have installed KDE plasma and I don't want to keep Unity anymore.

How I remove it completly??? In login screen I can see GNOME flashback (compiz) and (metacity), I want to remove them too.
How I remove lightDM also??? I have gdm already installed.

I'am using UBUNTU LTS desktop 14.04

Thanks for your answers and I apologize if it's a duplicated question.